# How to calculate a percentage using two groups within groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
+------+-----+-----+
| Year | Cat | Bin |
+------+-----+-----+
| 2000 | A   |   0 |
| 2000 | A   |   1 |
| 2001 | A   |   0 |
| 2001 | B   |   1 |
| 2001 | B   |   0 |
| 2001 | B   |   1 |
+------+-----+-----+

d = {
    'year': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001],
    'cat': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", ],
    'bin': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to create the following table:

```
+------+-----+------+-------+------+
| year | cat | mean | count | pct  |
+------+-----+------+-------+------+
| 2000 | A   |  0.5 |     2 | 100% |
| 2001 | A   |    0 |     1 | 25%  |
| 2001 | B   | 0.67 |     3 | 75%  |
+------+-----+------+-------+------+
```

Where `pct` is the percentage `count` by `cat` & `year` is of `count` by `year`.

I've got as far as the first two columns with:

```
df["count"] = 1
df_groupby = df.groupby(["year", "cat"]).agg({"bin": "mean", "count": "sum"})
df_groupby.rename(columns={"bin": "mean"}, inplace=True)
```

But I can't work out how to create the third column?

Answer (score 6):

Group on `year` and `cat` to calculate `mean` and `count`, then calculate the counts in year column using `value_counts` and divide this by the counts per `year` and `cat` to calculate the percentage

```
s = df.groupby(['year', 'cat'])['bin'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
s['pct'] = s['count'].div(df['year'].value_counts(), level=0, axis=0).mul(100)
```

---

```
              mean  count    pct
year cat                        
2000 A    0.500000      2  100.0
2001 A    0.000000      1   25.0
     B    0.666667      3   75.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and add new column by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.groupby("year")['cat'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
df1 = df.groupby(["year", "cat"]).agg(mean = ("bin", "mean"),
                                      count = ("bin", "count")).join(s.rename('pct'))

print (df1)
              mean  count    pct
year cat                        
2000 A    0.500000      2  100.0
2001 A    0.000000      1   25.0
     B    0.666667      3   75.0
```

Or by `assign`:

```
s = df.groupby("year")['cat'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
df1 = df.groupby(["year", "cat"]).agg(mean = ("bin", "mean"),
                                      count = ("bin", "count")).assign(pct = s)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the percentage, after getting `mean` and `count`, divide the intial `count` by the sum of the `count` grouped by year:

```
(df.groupby(['year', 'cat'])
   .agg(['mean', 'count'])
   .droplevel(0, 1)
   .assign(pct = lambda df: df['count'].div(df.groupby('year')['count']
                                              .transform('sum'))
                                              .mul(100)
                                           )
 )


              mean  count    pct
year cat                        
2000 A    0.500000      2  100.0
2001 A    0.000000      1   25.0
     B    0.666667      3   75.0
```

Note that for clarity, I'd suggest you do this in separate steps.